# Context in alertdialog

Tags: java, android, this, android-alertdialog

Here is the code for alert dialog I am using:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(AlertDemo.this)
    .setTitle("This is Alert Demo")
    .setMessage("Here is an Alert Message!")
    .setNeutralButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dlg, int sumthin) 
        {
            // do nothing – it will close on its own
        }
    })
    .show();
```

when i write `this` instead of `AlertDemo.this` it shows an error `The constructor AlertDialog.Builder(new View.OnClickListener(){}) is undefined`.. What does it mean ? what is the difference between `this` and `AlertDemo.this` ?

Comment: Where did you use this code, in the main activity?

Comment: AlertDialog is under button click.. when i press button alertdialog gets display...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply use `this`, it is an instance of inner class View.onClickListener

In order to show alertdialog on click of a button you need to pass the instance of you AlertDemo class.

That's why you use `AlertDemo.this`

Comment: Does it mean that we are passing context of AlertDemo.java ? If yes then what is the need to pass that context ? I mean to say ultimately what we are getting by passing that context ?

Comment: In order to create a new object of AlertDialog, we need to pass the instance of Activity. And only then we can create a new dialog.